# ~$ temporary files - Can they be hidden?

Tags: sharepoint-online

We've migrated 100s of folders from a network drive to SharePoint online. The folders in SharePoint show the ~$ temporary files whereas they were not visible to the end user in the network drive. Is there a way of hiding these temporary files? A search for ~$ in the document library only produced about 200 results (which I deleted).  Personally I would just ignore the temporary files but since their file structure doesn't look the same end users are complaining that their files haven't migrated over properly.  Any help would be much appreciated.